# Linking shared library with libm

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

I have a program which is linked (dynamically) with libm.
There are also several plugins for this program.
Plugins are loaded explicitely with dlopen().
Some of these plugins use round() from libm.

On one system (Linux Mint 19.1 gcc 7.5.0) the program
does not work because of unresolved round.

Here is simple example:

1. Library (lib.c)

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    void func(double a, double b)
    {
        double c;
        c = round(a + b);
        printf("c = %lf\n", c);
    }
   ```
2. Main program (main.c)

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <dlfcn.h>

    void *dll;
    void (*f)(double, double);
    double a = 1.234, b = 4.321;

    int main(void)
    {
        dll = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
        f = dlsym(dll, "func");
        f(a,b);
        return 0;
    }
   ```
3. Building (Makefile)

   ```
    all:
            gcc -Wall -Os -shared -fPIC lib.c -o lib.so
            gcc -Wall -Os -rdynamic -fPIC main.c -o main -ldl -lm
   ```
4. Run on Debian 8, gcc 4.9.2

   ```
     ./main 
    c = 6.000000
   ```
5. Run on Linux Mint 19.1, gcc 7.5.0

   ```
     ./main 
    ./main: symbol lookup error: ./lib.so: undefined symbol: round
   ```

Now, add -lm for dll compilation

```
    gcc -Wall -Os -shared -fPIC lib.c -o lib.so -lm

     ./main 
    c = 6.000000
```

So, the question is - why on this particular system one must use -lm not only for main program but for plugin also?

Answer (score 1):

Just like an executable program, shared libraries are linked entities (unlike static libraries which are archives of object files).

Since shared libraries are linked like executables, you also need to link with the libraries that your library depends on:

```
gcc -Wall -Os -shared -fPIC lib.c -o lib.so -lm
```

Comment: The question is why it is not need on many other systems - Debian 6 on i386, Debian 8,9 on amd64, Armbian on ARM (Orange PI, to be exact)

Comment: Check the default setting of linker option `--as-needed`. Anyways, you should link your libraries without unresolved symbols.

Comment: main program linked to libm;  dlls, loaded by main program with dlopen(), use symbols  from libm; should these dlls see these symbols? usually they do without linking them 'personally' to libm; what exactly wrong with Linux Mint 19.1?

Comment: @dee0xeed The behavior you seem to think is wrong is actually the *default* and standard behavior. Other distributions of the build-chain might add special flags to change this default behavior. Shared libraries and object should always be linked as stand-alone executables (except using the `-shared` flag to make them shared instead).

Comment: "Check the default setting of linker option" - all systems were used "out of the box", no special linker tunings was ever done.  The fact is that linker from 'Linux Mint 19.1' behaves differently - symbols from libm loaded by main program  at startup are not seen by shared libraries loaded by main program with dlopen()

Comment: @dee0xeed Those are different OS's with different programs, they are not bound to be compatible. For example `GNU ld` and `gold` are two different, not entirely compatible linkers.

Comment: "not entirely compatible linkers" - compatible with what? with itself?

Comment: No. `GNU ld` and `gold` (those are two different programs) aren't entirely compatible with _each other._

Comment: The default value of linker-option `--as-needed` is different in these systems. When it is set to _no_ then `libm.so` won't be linked into the main executable, as it doesn't use anything from libm.so